# How can I remove or invalidate RDD from Dstream?

Tags: apache-spark

To make it clear here is what I am doing.

```
@Override
public JavaRDD<Object> call(JavaPairRDD<Object, Iterable<JSONObject>> aggregatedRDD) throws Exception {
      try {
          ...
          Logic
          ...
      } catch (Exception e) {
          ...
          Invalidate or remove RDD from dStream
          ...
      }
}
```

**What I am trying**

I want to handle exception for the failed scenario and then remove RDD from the Dstream so that it is not moved to next node of DAG for processing. Moreover, knowing how can I remove RDD from dStream can be handy in other scenarios(I may want to transform an RDD to nothing).
I am new to Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to return an empty RDD in the case of an exception.

```
return sc.emptyRDD()
```

Comment: In java this can be done by ssc.sparkContext().emptyRDD();